# Xenocode Postbuild is not running on Windows 8

Tags: xenocode

I have downloaded Xenocode Postbuild 2009 for .Net (Beta) and installed it. I also have MS .Net Framework 3.5, 4, 4.5 properly installed on my PC. But Xenocode Postbuild is not running. When I double click on it, nothing comes up.
Any solution? Thanks in advance :) Please help :)